# On delete I want to redirect to the previous page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to delete the customised item from the list. I have 5 pages, in each 
page 6 items each (ie;total 30 items in list(including all pages), so that from 5th page I deleted the 6 items, when I deleted the all 6 items it is saying the your page is empty. Still in other four pagination pages includes the remaining items(26).

Please give me a solution.Any help

I want to redirect the 4th page, when 5th page items are empty. How can I achieve this?

`redirect_to :back` is not working here

my controller page

```
 def destroy
    @customised_dresses = CustomisedDress.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:id]).first
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customised_dresses.present?
        @customised_dresses.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "Customised dress has been successfully destroyed" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'You have no customised item.' }
      end
    end
 end
```

mycustomisations.html.slim
 `- if @customises
      - if @customises.empty?
        You have no items in your list
          = link_to 'Customise Dress', :customise_index, class: 'btn btn-primary'
      - else
    = paginate @customises`

Comment: 5 pages x 6 items per page - this is 30 items, not 20. Something in your numbers is wrong.

Comment: thanks @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: I think this should be handled in your `index` action. If you're requesting a page that does not exist, show the last existing page instead.

Comment: `  def index
    @customised_dresses = current_or_null_user.customised_dresses.where dress_id: params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which gem are you using for paginate?. Assuming that you are using "will paginate". You can try this after destroy:

```
last_page = @customises.total_pages
redirect_to: your_path(page: last_page)
```

Comment: thanks thanks thanks a lottttttt ....helped me from a big trouble :)  thanks again @Prakash Laxkar